# FutureBuilder is not building

Tags: dart

Do you know why the following FutureBuilder is not called when starting a stream and return to a Future?

Note: I know there is many ways to solve this with stream etc. This is for learning, so if you know why, I would like to know - thanks.

```
// import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFutureClass {
  Future<String> myF;

  setMyF() {
    this.myF = Future.value("Hello F");
  }

  Future<String> getMyF() {
    return myF;
  }
}

class MyFutureWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStreamWidget();

  final _myStreamClass = MyStreamClass();

  // var stream = countStream(10);
  // var sum = await sumStream(stream);
  // print(sum); // 55

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Add to future"),
            onPressed: () {
              _myStreamClass.setMyF();
            },
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            // future: _myStreamClass.getMyF(),
            future: _myStreamClass.myF),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              } else {
                return Text("No data");
              }
            },
          ),
        ]
            .map((c) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: c,
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With **StateFullWidget**: Just tryed using StateFullWidget, same result - FutureBuilder is not called?

```
// import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStreamClass {
  Future<String> myF;

  setMyF() {
    this.myF = Future.value("Hello F");
    this.myF.then((v) {
      print(v);
    });
  }

  Future<String> getMyF() {
    return myF;
  }
}

class MyStreamWidget extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
  _MyStreamWidget createState() => _MyStreamWidget();

}

class _MyStreamWidget extends State<MyStreamWidget> {
  final _myStreamClass = MyStreamClass();

  // var stream = countStream(10);
  // var sum = await sumStream(stream);
  // print(sum); // 55

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Add to future"),
            onPressed: () {
              _myStreamClass.setMyF();
            },
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _myStreamClass.myF,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              } else {
                return Text("No data");
              }
            },
          ),
        ]
            .map((c) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: c,
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ` return sum.toString();` in `sumStream` probably is never reached. This is only reached when the passed stream is closed otherwise it keeps waiting for more values

Comment: Yes, it do get reached - thanks

Comment: Your code is a bit weird. Try `onPressed: () {
              _myStreamClass.startStream(); setState((){});
            },` anyway to track down the cause.

Comment: It is a StatlessWidget - I started from this: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: Ok, that's where this is coming from. Better to make it stateful instead of moving state to a class that does not work well with Widget lifecycles.

Comment: Just added: lookAtThis.then((v) {
      print(v);}
      );

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks - I am trying to move into using Bloc's and from my understanding - this is all about keeping states in Bloc's. Thats is why I am investigating this. Thanks

Comment: Just simplified it a bit - only using Future<String>

Comment: But still a stateless widget that is supposed to update when the state changes.
Kinda what stateful widgets are for ;p

Comment: Hi again :-) Just tried with StateFullWidget - same result.

Comment: You should move the code from the class into the widget and call `setState(...)` to update the state.